# Extracting one letter (log level) from log file

Tags: regex, logging, websphere

i have a line of the log where log level is defined just by one letter W-Warning, E- Error ... How can i achieve to extract just that exact letter (letter E after CacheMessenge) from the whole log line ?

```
[11/26/18 15:36:43:781 CET] 00003734 CacheMessenge E   CWLLG2057E: A JMSException occurred with a linked Exception. Linked Error: CWSIT0008E: A successful connection was made to the bootstrap server at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
(?<=CacheMessenge\s)[A-Z]
```

> Explanantion

- `(?<=CacheMessenge\s)` - Positive look behind. Test for `CacheMessenge` before match.
- `[A-Z]` - Matches any one capital alphabet.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fKYSqO/1)